# Node.js is not accessible from external IPs on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, live

I try to access my node.js server running on Ubuntu. My PC is connected with TP-link router. Now, I want to access node services from other IP(not from my local host or local IPs). What can I do? I used following code.

Note: This server works fine and accessible from local IP but can't access from my public IP

```
http.listen(6000,"0.0.0.0",function(){
    log.info("server started");
})
```

Comment: What is the value of `PORT`?

Comment: Hrm, should be open, but likely an `iptables` block. Try something in the higher range like 8080 or 9000.

Comment: Lot of things that could be going on here.  I don't think this is related to NodeJS since your bind address is correct

Comment: i just use my public ip for access node server service but i can't, i think router not forward request to my local pc connected with router.

Comment: If it works from `localhost:6000`, then you're probably best post over on superuser.com for help forwarding ports on your router.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use :-

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp  --sport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

for the outgoing rule (not `dport`). Apart from that, maybe there's an earlier rule that blocks the traffic? Try `iptables -L`.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu have very good firewall and default system is not allow to external IP to response

In express and node js or any server  like that

```
http.listen(6000,"0.0.0.0",function(){
    log.info("server started");
})
```

It will work on your IP, localhost and public IP
but on external IP can't access it

first of all replace

```
localhost -> 0.0.0.0
```

when you want to run frontend and backend simultaneously
then it is better to use public IP directly instead of `0.0.0.0`

If you are using ubuntu then we need to change in firewall settings using ufw

UFW is installed by default on Ubuntu. If it has been uninstalled for some reason, you can install it with apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install ufw
```

then

```
 sudo nano /etc/default/ufw
```

check this line and make it yes

```
IPV6=yes
```

save file using Ctrl-X to exit the file, then shift + y to save the changes that you made, then ENTER

At any time, you can check the status of UFW with this command:

```
sudo ufw status verbose
```

By default, UFW is disabled so you should see something like this:

```
Output:
Status: inactive
```

Not most important point

```
sudo ufw allow portNumber // here portNumber is port-number in integer
```

in your case

```
sudo ufw allow 6000
```

and allow

```
sudo ufw allow http
```

for more rules and firewall on ubuntu [click here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-14-04)